# How long does a service worker keeps its cache?

Tags: javascript

I just got into Service Workers and made a simple setup for my site.

The documentation is quite good, but I wasn't able to find anywhere how much a service workers keeps the caches? I'm doing cache busting for my js and css assets (something like `bundle.[hash].js`) and I'm not sure if I should make sure to clean up the old assets from the cache manually or will they just expire in some time?

Comment: In @angular/service-worker we can set the `version` field of the `ngsw-config.json` and call `SwUpdate.checkForUpdate` to download the new files instead of loading the app files from the cache. With assetGroups it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache):

> Items in a Cache do not get updated unless explicitly requested; they don't expire unless deleted.

It seems that if you want a service worker to "expire", you need to handle it manually. So it would fetch the cached version, then see that it is out of date, and then either prompt the user to refresh or automatically refresh.

I think that's probably how [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-expiration) does it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the documentation?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/#toc-how

> When we're installed, the activation step will follow and this is a
>   *great opportunity for handling any management of old caches*, which
>   we'll cover during the *service worker update* section.

[image]

The page I linked to explains "How to Cache and Return Requests"

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {

  var cacheWhitelist = ['pages-cache-v1', 'blog-posts-cache-v1'];

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the cache age by controlling cache-controller :

`public

Expires: (sometime in the future, according session.cache_expire)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=(sometime in the future, according to session.cache_expire)
Last-Modified: (the timestamp of when the session was last saved)`

and also,

`<?php
header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800' );
/* now get and send images */
?>`

see Here :
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php)

Comment: The question is not tagged as `PHP` so the OP is not using php. Also, the question is about the service worker cache (pwa), not the http cache.